# optaplanner how to dynamic add or edit rules

Tags: java, optaplanner

[image]

[image]

[image]

My question is whether you can add or edit the scoring rules without restarting the project and changing the back-end code

Comment: Beyond using `@ConstraintConfiguration` to dynamically enable/disable constraints, generating constraints on the fly (for example with the ConstraintStreams API) aren't available out of the box yet.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Consider pasting your actual code as text rather than screenshots. The editing tool provides a neat way to format your code. Posting screenshots of your code is frowned upon here.